# React Native - Create uri for an image with a variable

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**Question #1:**

How to create a uri with a link and a variable? My example is from an API.

```
<Image source={{uri: 'http://www.mypage.com/'+`${val.images.filename}`}}  style={styles.imgProd} />
```

**Question #2:**

I would also like to know how to build the uri with a function like something like this.

```
makeImgUrl(value) {
    if (value === '' || valueUrl === 'null') {
        return ("http://www.mypage.com/defaultimg.jpg")
    } else {
        return ("http://www.mypage.com/"+${value})
    }
}

<Image source={{uri: +makeImageUrl(val.images.filename)}}  style={styles.imgProd} />
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `string interpolation` wrongly.

```js
let name = 'John';

console.log('Hi! I am ' + name); //ES5

console.log(`Hi! I am ${name}`)
```

As shown above, either we go for ES5 way, which we don't use backtick at all, or we opt for ES6 way, remove the single-quote/double-quote and replace with backtick.

So apply whatever I said onto your scenario, it would be as below

```
<Image source={{uri: 
`http://www.mypage.com/${val.images.filename}`}}  style={styles.imgProd} />
```

or

```
<Image source={{uri: 
'http://www.mypage.com/' + val.images.filename}}  style={styles.imgProd} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add variable with url concating with + like below :

```
<Image source={{uri: 'http://www.mypage.com/'+val.images.filename}}  style={styles.imgProd}/>
```

OR call function like :

```
function makeImgUrl(value) {
    if (value === '' || valueUrl === 'null') {
        return "http://www.mypage.com/defaultimg.jpg"
    } else {
        return "http://www.mypage.com/"+value
    }
}

<Image source={{ uri: makeImageUrl(val.images.filename) }}  style={styles.imgProd} />
```